# PHP echo content of HTML page not working correctly

Tags: html, echo, file-get-contents, php

I am trying to use the following php code to display another html page. Sadly nothing is printed on the screen, and yes I have checked and confirmed that the link works. Any thoughts on why this could be happening would be helpful thank you.

```
$site = readfile("http://k9minecraft.tk/thanks.html");
echo $site;
```

Comment: what do you expect? may be the CSS and Image links do not work! view source in your browser!

Comment: I should be seeing that thanks.html page. Source of the php file is empty.

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw The thanks.html does have some css scripting styles, is that affecting it?

Comment: check allow_url_fopen is set to true in your php.ini

Comment: I don't seem to have any access to that as it is with a hosting company but I can call them and see what they say.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, that also didn't seem to do anything. I think you may be on to something with that.

Comment: @Kyle Ignore my previous comment, the allow_url_fopen can only be set in php.ini and is disabled on most hostings for security reasons. You can ask your host to enable it.

Comment: try adding php_value allow_url_fopen On to a htaccess file in the directory you want it to work in

Comment: Alright so adding the allow_url_fopen to true worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure php is configured so that allow_url_fopen is on.

If you want to save the string to a variable, try using file_get_contents instead since it adds the file to memory. Refer [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for more detailed information on official documentation.

```
$site = file_get_contents("http://k9minecraft.tk/thanks.html");
echo $site;
```

The readfile function reads the file directly to the output buffer, so it doesn't require an echo. Refer [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) for more detailed information on official documentation.

```
readfile("http://k9minecraft.tk/thanks.html");
```

readfile is more efficient in terms of memory usage, whereas file_get_contents more useful in many situations.

Comment: Tried it, but also returned a blank page. Does it matter that my thanks.html has css scripting in it?

Comment: I dont think it should be blank.  if the page is too large, file_get_contents might not work properly.  you can try it with just readfile("http://k9minecraft.tk/thanks.html"); and no echo

Comment: I tried just this with no variable assignment or echo and got a blank page still. readfile("http://k9minecraft.tk/thanks.html");

Answer (score 0):

[**`readfile()`**](https://www.php.net/readfile) actually returns just the number of characters read from the file. The content of the file is stored in buffer.

1. Turn output buffering OFF.
2. Use something like [**`ob_end_flush`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php)

Check [**`this`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#81032) too...It may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
//other php codes here
?>
<a href="http://k9minecraft.tk/thanks.html" class="classname" id="idname">Link Name</a>
<?php
//continue other php codes.
?>
```

how about that ? Without using readfile.